Django Site + Model Translation
I am working on a Django website and I want to have multiple languages for the website.
The project has a model called Product. Product has 3 fields ( name, description and info ) that I would like to be translated for all of the Product Objects. I would also like to translate the static parts of the website ( navbar, footer, etc ).
What would be the best approach to do that?
